# How to expand android ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How can i expand the actionbar like PlayNewsstand application and the image below :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i am looking for found it [here](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar).

Answer (score 0):

For your concern try using this in your manifest file ..

```
yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Ex:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Complete reference :: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: how can i expand and collapse the actionbar not to create an actionbar ?

Comment: yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" expands your action bar to different parts based on your device size automatically.

Comment: showAsAction="ifRoom" shows **buttons** on the bar, if there is room, and in the overflow menu, if no room. it does not alter the bar itself.